# When I try to redirect to any other page it goes to http://localhost:5050/login instead of http://localhost:5050/todo/login

Tags: spring-mvc, tomcat8

I am using Spring MVC for web application development. When I manually deploy the application war file in Tomcat (todo.war) it deploy at http://localhost:5050/todo/

First page is on http://localhost:5050/todo/login its working fine but when I try to redirect to any other page it goes to
http://localhost:5050/list instead of http://localhost:5050/todo/list.

In my web.xml I have given url pattern as / only

When I am typing my url manually i.e. http://localhost:5050/todo/list required page is loading.

In Eclipse IDE the application is deployed at http://localhost:5050/ only in that it is working fine. I am using Maven packaging of my web application.

Comment: Could you show readers your configuration files?

Comment: Please stop overwriting my good edits ([edit history](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/66940195/revisions)).

Comment: Please add the code used to perform the redirect. Are you using [`HttpServletResponse#sendRedirect`](https://jakarta.ee/specifications/servlet/4.0/apidocs/javax/servlet/http/httpservletresponse#sendRedirect-java.lang.String-) perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

As you have mentioned that url pattern is /, it will try to look for the page from /

As your application is todo and list page is inside the app, your url pattern should be /todo in web.xml , then it should route to all the pages and files inside the todo app

Try this change and see if it works

Thank you